# letsrate gem - is not creating rates on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a letsrate gem https://github.com/muratguzel

I have installed it and followed the instructions on the readme page.
I have placed on the page:

```
<div class="shop-review-ratings">
                  Service: <%= rating_for @shop, "service" %>
                  Price: <%= rating_for @shop, "price" %>
</div>
```

BUt, when on controller side, I try to save the ratings with this line:

```
@shop.rate(params[:stars], current_user.id, params[:dimension])
```

it says:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "stars" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (24, 3, 1576, Shop, null, null, 2013-06-01 10:13:28.297843, 2013-06-01 10:13:28.297843).

: INSERT INTO "rates" ("created_at", "dimension", "rateable_id", "rateable_type", "rater_id", "stars", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id">
```

and my params says:

```
{"score"=>"4", "controller"=>"shops", "action"=>"rate"}
```

I have run all the migration that were needed. And placed under `shop.rb`:

```
letsrate_rateable "service", "price"
```

Have anybody used this gem, and has a hint how this can be fixed, or does have an working example for this gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have found my answer. The ratings ARE updating. I have been trying to test on the record that I have been already rated, and nothing happened - and it is because it is forbidding a user to rate again, so nothing was happening. I tried to rate new shop, and it was working. Thanks anyways for everyone that started looking on this problem.